# Greek equivelent to Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata

Tags: ancient-greek, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I have been working my way though Ørberg's *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata*, and I have been wondering whether there is an equivalent text for learning Ancient Greek by the "natural method."

A quick google search lead to "[Lingua Graeca per se Illustrata](https://github.com/seumasjeltzz/LinguaeGraecaePerSeIllustrata)," which is not really what I was thinking of because it is an open source internet thing unlike LLPSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the effectiveness of any of these, but this question was asked on the [Ancient Greek subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AncientGreek/comments/bdmu2f/learn_ancient_greek_by_natural_way/) and a few suggestions were offered. Athenaze is one (which you likely have heard of), but if you scroll there are additional options.